# jsoup equation of nextelementsibling and lastelementsibling

Tags: jsoup, equation, siblings

I'm trying to check the equation of nextElementSibling() and lastElementSibling() of an object in a conditional statement on jsoup. This is how I tried it:

```
if(op.nextElementSibling().equals(op.lastElementSibling()))
{
 ...
}
```

But when I run it, the app craches because it returns always "false".
What is the problem with this statement and how could I fix the equation?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question needs improvement. Please give us more of your code. Prepare a working/failing example that lets us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you add to your post the HTML or XML code you're trying to parse please?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to control the last loop that passes the last element but when the last loop came the op.nextElementSibling() returned null and somehow the app crashed. I made another conditional statement before all others to check if the nextElementSibling would be null and that is how I solved the problem.